# grunt-webpack says it's "done without errors" but hasn't bundled anything

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, npm, webpack

So I am trying to get grunt, babel and webpack to play nicely together, but after a week of trying various things I researched, nothing really worked. So here is the relevant part of my gruntfile.js:

```
webpack: {
        options: {
            entry: ['./js/main'],
            output: {
                filename: 'bundle.js'
            },
            module: {
                loaders: [
                    {
                        test: /\.js$/,
                        loader: 'babel-loader',
                        query: {
                            presets: ['es2015', 'react']
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
        },
    }
```

Obviously, there is a main.js in the "js" folder:

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

import Message from './Message' //Message.js also exists

ReactDOM.render(<Message/>, document.getElementById('react-container'));
```

I would think if there is something wrong in the requirements etc., grunt web pack would complain, but instead the result is:

```
grunt webpack
Done, without errors.
```

with no bundle.js created. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to replace `options` with something else. `options` is a reserved key for options of the grunt plugin.

So this should work:

```
webpack: {
    myconfig: {
        entry: ['./js/main'],
        ...
    },
}
```